# Import gives undefined in Typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am a newbie at using typeorm. The project that I am working on I created all entities. Then, I wanted to make imports cleaner. The code crashes due to the fact that I made it imports like the below example.

I export the files from 'entities/index.ts'

```
import Account from './Account';
import Order from './Order';

export {
    Account,
    Order,
};
```

Thus, I can import all entities once.

```
import { Account, Order } from '@entities/index'
```

PS: The above example is a dummy in order to show the case.

**The problem** is that I faced. When I run the application it shows me undefined. I tried to direct import like

```
import Account from '@entities/Account';
```

Then it works. But I don't want to make like that. If I do like that, the imports will look bad. 
You can see below in the example how I debug it. (BaseEntity gives undefined)

User.ts

[image]

BaseEntity.ts

[image]

entities/index.ts

[image]

**Result**
[image]

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Btw, just for information. I already use this system in the project. It definitely works. I had used mongoose, I had decided to change the DB, then I had started to convert the project. Right now, I face this issue :/

Comment: Without seeing all the imports for all the files we can't be sure, but googling `Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined` it seems the answer is often that there's a cyclical dependency.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.
Yes, but to make a relation between entities, as I understood. I make it a cyclical dependency. Like in the example. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md

You can see the example. `Photo.ts` imports `User.ts`, `User.ts` imports `Photo.ts`

Comment: This article seems to get at the core problem of dependency load order when there is a cyclic dependency.  https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de So the load order might be Account, BaseEntity, User and `User` has not fully loaded by the time Account needs it.

Comment: Thanks @Jim

The article helped me with that, indeed.  If you write a short answer to the question, I can approve the answer. It can help people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a javascript circular dependency, rather than a TypeORM problem.  This article seems to get at the core problem of dependency load order when there is a cyclic dependency. [Circular Dependency Issues](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) So the load order might be `Account, BaseEntity, User` and `User` has not fully loaded by the time `Account` needs it.